# select from a table that matches its column to and id or childeren of that id in another table and limit duplicate items to 10

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have two table named as regions and data.

```
regions
<Id>, <Name>, <ParentId>
1      a          0
2      b          0
3      c          1

data
<Id>, <Url>, <RegionId>
1     "..."     3
2     "..."     2
3     "..."     1
4     "..."     1
```

excepted result When use WHERE regions.ParentId=0 condition

```
<data.Id>, <CatId>, <data.Url>
     3        1        ""
     4        1        ""
     2        2        ""
     1        1        ""
```

I want get data records that data.RegionId is matches to regions.Id or matches the children of regions.Id and ... . Then create new Column named CatId that should be regions.Id that have child ParentId=0.
I need to set limit for items per CatId. e.g. 10

Comment: MySQL has no native support for hierarchical data or recursive queries.  You will need to do this with a loop, possibly as a stored procedure.

Comment: can you present it in php?

Comment: Can the parent of a region have its own parent?

Comment: @DavidAman what's your mean?

Comment: I mean, if Id = 3 has ParentId = 1, can Id = 4 have ParentId = 3? In other words, can you have multiple levels of parenthood?

Answer (score 0):

It's answer half of you question return the data record that matches regionid or parent id

```
select d.id , r.id as catid ,d.url 
from data d join regions r  on r.id = d.regionId 
union
select d.id , r.id  as catid ,d.url 
from data d join regions r  on r.parentid = d.regionId
```

now tell me what you really like to get so we can give the right answer